# Wireless does not work anymore after software update with Ubuntu 12.10 on a Dell Latitude E6230

Tags: wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my DELL Latitude E6230, on first boot wifi worked properly but when I updated the software it stopped working. I can't figure out the problem...

The wireless network controller is a Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless Lan Controller (rev 01)

"lshw -class network" gives, for the above controller:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Network controller
    product: BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
    vendor: Broadcom Corporation
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
    version: 01
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:f7d00000-f7d03fff
```

After reading the answer to another similar question, I edited the file
NetworkManager.conf to make "managed=true", but that did not make any difference,
it is as if the wireless adapter were not there. In the "Network" setting window,
I only see "Wired" and "Network proxy". Wireless has just disappeared:

```
rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and that's it! Nothing about the wireless controller...

Any suggestions?