# Ran "software update", and wireless is gone

Tags: wireless

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless doesn’t work on a Broadcom BCM4312](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125529/wireless-doesnt-work-on-a-broadcom-bcm4312)

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 amd64 on a macbook 3,1.  Wireless was working until I ran a "software update", and now I am without wireless.

I have an internal Broadcom Network Adaptor (BCM4321).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks similar to mine, and I think the new kernel and broadcom drivers are the connection.  I ran

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

which I found here -
[Wireless does not work anymore after software update with Ubuntu 12.10 on a Dell Latitude E6230](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214156/wireless-does-not-work-anymore-after-software-update-with-ubuntu-12-10-on-a-dell)

and it worked for me on my Acer Laptop.