# Lost Wi-Fi after Ubuntu 12.10 (Precise Pangolin) upgrade

Tags: wireless, 12.10, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install BCM43142 wireless drivers for Dell Vostro 3460/3560?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560)
>   [Ubuntu 12.10, Wireless not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/213550/ubuntu-12-10-wireless-not-working)

I received my new [Dell Vostro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_Vostro) 2420 last week and just got around to upgrading from Ubuntu 11.10 (Oneiric Ocelot) to Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal).

Unfortunately, like many others (after researching the issue), I no longer have Wi-Fi. I have tried every `sudo` command given that worked for others and still can't get my wireless to function.

I can connect via Ethernet, just not via Wi-Fi. As a matter of fact, when I use Fn + F2 to turn on Wi-Fi, only my [Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth) comes on.

```
lspci 
 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)

 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)

 00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)

 00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)

 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)

 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)

 00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)

 00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)

 00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)

 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)

 00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)

 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)

 07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation Device 4365 (rev 01)

 09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

---

This is what I am getting...

> dpkg: error: --install needs at least one package archive file argument
>
> Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
>   Use `dselect` or `aptitude` for user-friendly package management;
>   Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
>   Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
>   Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;
>
> Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through `less` or `more` !

Answer (score 1):

I have the same hardware and had the same problem.

To fix, I downloaded/installed the http://jas.gemnetworks.com/debian/pool/main/w/wireless-bcm43142/wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb .

Open a terminal, copy and paste the following:

```
wget http://jas.gemnetworks.com/debian/pool/main/w/wireless-bcm43142/wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb
```

I found this solution from: [Dell Vostro 2420 upgrade to 12.04.1 no wifi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/202700/dell-vostro-2420-upgrade-to-12-04-1-no-wifi)

Simply downloading/installing the above deb should work for you as long as you are using Ubuntu 12.10 **64bit**.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Please can you open up a terminal and issue **lspci** then post the output? Also have you tried connecting via LAN?

Good you have a Broadcom Corporation Device 4365. Most people get affected after a kernel upgrade. First, install the prerequisites by opening a terminal and pasting, one line at a time:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers$(uname -r | grep -Po "\-[a-z].*")
sudo apt-get install build-essential dkms
```

If your PC is 32-bit/i386 then open a terminal and copy/paste the following

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/n76dcsdtayvp0wm/wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_i386.deb
```

If 64-bit/amd64 then open a terminal and copy/paste the following

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/jerkl6uqal5ylv3/wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i wireless-bcm43142-dkms-6.20.55.19_amd64.deb
```

The suggestion was gotten from [BCM43142 wireless drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175104/how-do-i-install-bcm43142-wireless-drivers-for-dell-vostro-3460-3560/175115#175115)

Please let me know if it works!

Comment: Steven tried to add the results as an edit to your answer (rejected edit).  He didn't understand the instructions and says: "This is what I am getting...

dpkg: error: --install needs at least one package archive file argument"

You'll need to be a bit more explicit in your instructions.

Comment: Thanks @fabricator4 I've made my instructions more explicit. Hopefully it helps Steven. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the new kernel and broadcom drivers are the reason for the problem. Run

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Now your wireless should start working.

---

[Source:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214156/wireless-does-not-work-anymore-after-software-update-with-ubuntu-12-10-on-a-dell)