# Bluetooth firmware problem in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: bluetooth

I have a [Dell Inspiron][1] 15R 5520 laptop. Bluetooth is not working at all.

`rfkill list all` gives

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth

    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

1: phy0: Wireless LAN

    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN

    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`dmesg|grep -i bluetooth` gives

```
[   13.644428] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.16
[   13.644445] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   13.644453] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   13.644455] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   13.644461] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   15.861363] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   15.903443] Bluetooth: can't load firmware, may not work correctly
[   17.332535] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   17.332538] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   17.332544] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   17.393768] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   17.393781] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   17.393783] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

hciconfig gives

```
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: E0:06:E6:D5:DB:46  ACL MTU: 1021:8  SCO MTU: 64:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:687 acl:0 sco:0 events:56 errors:0
    TX bytes:2024 acl:0 sco:0 commands:52 errors:0
```

I have visited the site http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43 and according to it

`lspci -vnn -d 14e4`: gives

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365]
 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1704 802.11n + BT 4.0 [1028:0016]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at c1500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>    
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

So I got my PCI-ID as 14e4:4365 which it says is not supported. The alternative is wl.

What should I do?

My Wi-Fi is working normally without any problems, but Bluetooth is not working.

```
sudo dpkg -i wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb gives following error 
(Reading database ... 208543 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking wireless-bcm43142-dkms (from wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up wireless-bcm43142-dkms (6.20.55.19-1) ...
Loading new wireless-bcm43142-6.20.55.19 DKMS files...
Building only for 3.8.0-23-generic
Building initial module for 3.8.0-23-generic
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/apport/package-hooks/dkms_packages.py", line 22, in <module>
    import apport
ImportError: No module named apport
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.8.0-23-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/wireless-bcm43142/6.20.55.19/build/make.log for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your laptop's bluetooth device is attached to USB, not PCI bus?
Try `lsusb` and see if it comes up. E.g. (on my machine):

```
$ lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0 [ThinkPad]
...
```

You should also update BIOS first, if you have any hardware detection problems.

This will probably come as off-topic here, but I'll briefly describe how I managed to update BIOS on a Dell laptop:

- download FreeDOS pre-built ISO image and use it to make a bootable USB drive;
- download BIOS update from Dell support site, make sure you get the version that will run under DOS
- boot into FreeDOS and run the BIOS update.

Answer (score 0):

This bluetooth chip is not supported by kernel drivers. To get it work. it is better to report a bug at launchpad. It needs to be added to btusb driver and also you will need to convert and add firmware for that. Anyway it it can't be solved here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try this, and type in the terminal this:

```
 sudo apt-get install dkms
 sudo apt-get install blueman
 sudo dpkg-reconfigure Bluetooth
```

and it might work fine this way.

Answer (score -1):

For a **64-bit** Ubuntu installation, you can<sup>[1]</sup>:

- Download the file http://jas.gemnetworks.com/debian/pool/main/w/wireless-bcm43142/wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb
- Issue `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential dkms`
- Issue `sudo dpkg -i wireless-bcm43142-dkms_6.20.55.19-1_amd64.deb`

Even more answers are in the *Ask Ubuntu* question *[Lost WiFi after 12.10 upgrade](https://askubuntu.com/questions/227394/lost-wifi-after-12-10-upgrade)*.

<sub>1. From the official Ubuntu forum, *[Broadcom BCM43142 Driver Ubuntu 12.10 64 Bit](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2123154)*.</sub>

Comment: i did the three steps above and they worked without any problem but still bluetooth is not working

Comment: This has nothing to do with bluetooth problem